# How to disable and hide the pagination footer for react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm new to react-table. Currently, I have a 5 rows table to render on react-table, and I don't need the pagination function. I understand turning pagination off, it can be done by `"pagination={false}"`. However, the pagination control still showing, is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 21):

I just found prop `showPagination={false}`. Try that.

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#props

Answer (score 3):

you can add props like this in ReactTable

```
showPaginationBottom={false}
```

you can also decide to show pagination on basis of data rows length

```
showPaginationBottom={data.length > 10 ? true: false}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Table dataSource={DataSource} columns={columns} pagination={false} />
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.