# How to disable editing of React-Table jump page input?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am working on `react-table` and I want to disable the page input of the table.

[image]

As you can see in the image above. I want to disable that input. How can I do that?

This is the code that is generating react table:

```
<Table className="-striped"
     columns={this.columns}
     data={this.props.stockItems}
     defaultPageSize={10}
     defaultFilterMethod={this.filterCaseInsensitive}
     />
```

Comment: Have a look on: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324852/504807, does it answer your question?

Comment: @yoni No, that prop disables pagination completely.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I have updated the question with code. Actually this is very basic react-table implementation and I want to highlighted part in the image, which is input to jump to the desired page, I want to disable that, is there any react-table prop?

Comment: According to the documentation of older versions, there is a boolean prop called `showPageJump` that you can set to `false`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you update your question with what version of React Table you're using? The prop I mentioned in the previous comment is no longer available in v7.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yeah It worked like charm! Thanks! You can provide it in the answer below.

Comment: Glag I could help.

Comment: Saani, just wondering if you missed assigning the bounty or if you think my answer is still incomplete.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi it'll take 20 hours before I assign it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `react-table@v6` [documentation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#props). You can set the `showPageJump` boolean prop to `false` to disable the jump to page input.

```js
<Table className="-striped"
       columns={this.columns}
       data={this.props.stockItems}
       defaultPageSize={10}
       defaultFilterMethod={this.filterCaseInsensitive}
       showPageJump={false}
/>
```